# jQuery scrollTo with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use the jQuery scrollTo plugin with my Bootstrap 3 site, but I'm having a few issues with the scroll offset and active state.

The problem with the offset is it will apply when I add the code:

```
<script>    
$('#top-nav').onePageNav({
currentClass: 'active',
changeHash: true,
scrollSpeed: 1200,
scrollOffset: 70
}); </script>
```

But when I test this the site will scroll to where it should with the offset included and then jump to the position it would have scrolled to without the offset in place.

The active state I can't seem to get to apply on page load. With another site I used smooth scroll on, I remember just adding the active class to the home link and it worked perfect, and switched when another link was clicked.

Thanks for taking your time to check out my problem.

Link to the site: [Arkito Designs](http://www.mmwebco.co.uk/arkitodesigns)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the animate function from jquery with scrollTop.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
```

You might want to check the Jquery animate page: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That code doesn't seem to do anything at all :( I've checked the jquery animate page but can't find anything that would help my problem

Comment: Did you also tried putting the event inside the document.ready()?

Comment: I'm trying it now but I don't know too much js, I'm just trying to go from the little I do know. Should it look like this? $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
        };

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets stuck with this again the fix was to go into the OnaPageNav js and remove the newloc code in the onAfter function